# how to copy custom roles from database1 to database 2

Tags: marklogic

I have some custom roles (Role Name, Execute Privileges, URI Privileges, Permissions, Collections) and need to copy to another database in a different server.

What is the best way to copy custom roles from database1 to database2?

Comment: It's generally recommended to use a deployment tool such as ml-gradle to manage deployment of objects such as roles across multiple environments. In your shoes, I would consider writing something to export these to a JSON form ml-gradle could then deploy.

Comment: @rob-s consider putting that in an answer..